# Open a view over the tabbarcontroller

Tags: view, navigation, tabbarcontroller

this a very basic question but i don't know how to make pop a view over the tabbarcontroller for exemple i got a tabbar and i got a 'add' baritembutton
and i want a view to come from down and don't see the tabbar anymore.

thx

Answer (score 2):

Use presentModalViewController:

```
[yourTabBarController presentModalViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

where viewController is the view controller you want to show

To remove the modal view controller use:

```
[yourTabBarController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: nice but do you know how to remove it?